# Can I Delta hedge Swaption with 1month option expiry on 10 year swap as 1 month forward starting swap (expiry 10 yr) & notional as Delta% of swaption

Tags: swaps, delta-hedging, swaption

Whether below is correct

1 month expiry of swaption with 10 year swap underlying can be delta hedged as with below swap:

Notional of swap = delta% of swaption multiplied by notional of swaption
As of today swap is 1 month forward starting with expiry of 10 years

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the correct delta hedge for a swaption is an amount of the underlying forward swap.  Calculating the delta % is not trivial, as different models give different results.